# Why isn't there a way to hire people from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

My questions aren't getting the help I need. The bounty system is only so helpful... I don't have access anywhere else to a trustworthy method of both finding and vetting help.

I often get responses from very qualified and experienced people on here, but since this is essentially volunteer help I can only expect so much. 
Is there some prohibition against offering to hire Stack Overflow users? Yes, I looked at the jobs tab before I posted this and didn't see a straightforward way to post a job.

Comment: [jobs.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Comment: Look up at the top line, don't you see "Jobs"?

Comment: jobs only show people looking to hire, I don't see an option to post a job.

Comment: If you scroll down a bit you'll find a button on the right that says "Hiring developers? Post a job"

Comment: @Spilot - I don't get you. Jobs is for those looking to hire someone. You are looking to hire someone. Why do you think Jobs isn't for you?

Comment: Stack Overflow Talent: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Comment: @ChrisF... on desktop SO, the hire someone option is  in a very weird place on the page. Not at the top or bottom where you'd expect the option to be. It's on the far right midscreen, easy to scroll right past. It's a head scratcher why it wouldn't be there on the top menu bar with the other options or the very bottom of the page.

Comment: @ChrisF have you looked at the page and its awkward page real estate? It's why I posted the question in the first place. I couldn't see what I was looking for..

Comment: The primary reason is that StackOverflow is *not* a freelancer website. If you want a freelancer, find a site which specializes in that area.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***If*** a user is open to being hired for project work, you'll easily be able to tell because they'll say so on their profile and provide a way to get in contact. So if you run into a user that's being helpful but you need more from them than you feel you can reasonably expect, click through to their profile and see what it says. I've seen several profiles mentioning availability for large or small contracts.

Alternately: Post a listing on [jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) and comment on the question or answer you need more help with linking to that listing, so people can come to you.

Comment: it's an illusion that you can post a job directly to the jobs listings page. You have to go through a middle man form and then wait for them to get back to you ...with what? I don't know. I just want to post a gig to the board and I can't do that. Maybe they have to see if what I'm looking for is up to a certain standard before they allow the gig to go up on the board.

Comment: @Spilot: Well, *we* (the people who would be hired) don't want "gig"s posted "to the board". We want actual, professional jobs where there is some reasonable assurance that all parties are acting in good faith. If you can't handle "a middle man form", if you can't take the time for SE to get back to you, then yours is probably not a job we want posted on our site.

Comment: @Spilot I think that, minimally, they want to make sure you're not a scammer/spammer. IIRC, that used to be an issue right after they added Careers.

Comment: @NicolBolas my sentiment behind the comment that got you mad is this: If people are freaking out about how ostensibly silly it is that I asked the original question I asked (see the 15 downvotes and sarcastic comments ), then surely its because they don't know that the jobs option in the menu is not what it seems. It's not for newbs like me to trot along with debugging gigs, it's for established important people with companies, which is why its not easy to just post a job there, and why I'm not a moron for inquiring about it.

Comment: *then surely its because they don't know that the jobs option in the menu is not what it seems. It's not for newbs like me to trot along with debugging gigs* @Spilot I can't speak for anyone else but I did assume you were looking to hire someone for a period of time, not just as a one off. Usually users who just want to pay someone to answer a question put it in those terms "pay someone to answer". Your question talks about multiple questions and used the word "hire" so I got the wrong idea.

Comment: @BSMP I didnt see any option for "pay someone to answer" term when posting a question. Is it still available? How to pay someone for answering my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I *completely* understand the desire.

This makes a lot of sense from a demand perspective. Here's a person with a technical problem; there's thousands of persons *already solving technical problems.* You have a problem that is a bit more localized, and you are prepared to pay for the help. That's laudable; nothing wrong with that at all!

However, a formalized Stack Overflow gigs board would likely introduce *extremely* harmful dynamics into the site.

We already have huge problems with people gaming the system, posting trivial answers to trivial questions, plagiarizing content, etc. all to gain worthless rep points. Imagine how that would explode if points were a direct, institutionalized route to getting hired for small jobs.

It'd be a nightmare.  I'd go as far as to say, it would have the potential to destroy the community.

Comment: Migrate them to experts exchange? ;)